# how to compute transition in a N X N matrix where the dimensions are not not sequential

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, zip

I have the following data:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


arr = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 5])
x = pd.Series([0,1,2,3,4,6,7,0,1,2,3,4,6,7,0,1,2,3,4,6,7,0,1,2,3,4,5,7,0,1,2,3,4,6,7,0,1,2,3,4,6,7,0,1,2,3,4,6,7,0,1,2,3,4,6,7,0,1,2,3,4,6,7,0,1,2,3,4,6,7,0,1,0,1,2,3,4,6,7,0,1,2,3,4,6,7,0,1,2,3,4,6,7,0,1,2,3,4,6,7,0,1,0,1,2,3,4,6,7,0,1,2,3,4,6,7,0,1,2,3,4,6,7,0,1,2,3,4,6,7]) 

print(arr)
print(type(arr))
[0 1 2 3 4 6 7 5]
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

The code below works fine with the data above:

```
m = [[0] * len(arr) for _ in enumerate(arr)]

for (i, j) in zip(x, x[1:]):
    m[i][j] += 1
```

However, when the data is as below: the above code produces the following error:

```
arr = np.arry([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7])
x = pd.Series([0,1,2,3,4,6,7,0,1,2,3,4,6,7,0,1,2,3,4,6,7,0,1,2,3,4,6,7,0,1,2,3,4,6,7,0,1,2,3,4,6,7,0,1,2,3,4,6,7,0,1,2,3,4,6,7,0,1,2,3,4,6,7,0,1,2,3,4,6,7,0,1,2,3,4,6,7])
```

error--

m[i][j] += 1
IndexError: list index out of range
'''

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what @Ananda is correct, but what you wrote will still work, the real problem is that you are passing in two different types

the top is

```
arr = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 5])
```

and the bottom is

```
arr = np.arry([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7]])
```

you need the bottom to be

```
arr = np.arry([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7])
```

note the missing second set of brackets...

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you meant to do here.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


arr = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7])
x = pd.Series([0,1,2,3,4,6,7,0,1,2,3,4,6,7,0,1,2,3,4,6,7,0,1,2,3,4,6,7,0,1,2,3,4,6,7,0,1,2,3,4,6,7,0,1,2,3,4,6,7,0,1,2,3,4,6,7,0,1,2,3,4,6,7,0,1,2,3,4,6,7,0,1,2,3,4,6,7])

m = [[0] * (np.max(arr)+1) for _ in enumerate(np.arange(np.max(arr)+1))]

for (i, j) in zip(x, x[1:]):
    m[i][j] += 1
```

You need to take the maximum of the `arr` while creating your variable `m` and  and not it's length.

Comment: Now, I got a different error when I run the following code: `         for row in m:
        s = sum(row)
        if s > 0:
            row[:] = [f / s for f in row]
        transition_matrix = m

        for i in transition_matrix:
        assert sum(i[:]) == 1, "Does not sums up to 1, check transition matrix"
` The error: AssertionError: Does not sums up to 1, check transition matrix

Comment: That sounds like a completely different error altogether. You should it's better not to try to fix more than one error per question because it's difficult to understand from your post what is the issue. If your original issue is solved, please consider closing this question and posting it as a new one.